# Mongoose find() field that has spaces

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, backend

I am creating an endpoint in nodejs to query a mongodb collection which field has a space in "Loan ID".

```
{
   " Loan ID " : 674.0,
   " Amount " : " $50,000 ",
   "Tenor" : "3"
}
```

The code that I am using is as such.

```
exports.view = function (req, res) {
    LoanStat.findOne({ 'Loan ID' : req.body.id}, function (err, loanStat) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json({
            message: 'LoanStat details loading..',
            data: loanStat
        });
    });
};
```

Because of that space in the field "Loan ID", i cant seem to return a result. But if I were to query a field that has no spaces like "Tenor", my API works perfectly fine.

I working on creating an API for an existing database, if it were me I would never have named by fields this way.

Please help! thanks!

Comment: The `"Loan ID"` is hardcoded in your code? I tested changing that field in MongoDB and It worked

Comment: @luckongas omg you saved the day. Your reply got me looking at my schema and i found the mistake. Apparently it was " Loan ID " and I was querying "Loan ID". I feel silly now

Comment: No problem! Those things happen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently I was fooled by the additional blank spaces. The field was " Loan ID " and not "Loan ID". Failed to notice the extra blank spaces at the front and back.

Answer (score 0):

```
    exports.view = function (req, res);
{
      const data = LoanStat.findOne({ 'Loan ID' : req.body.id}).pretty();
    };
```

Comment: haha thank you but i found my answer in an earlier response already. i shall mark it as answer found